# assembleRelease not found in task gradle in Jenkins

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project. and it has 2 flavors whit names GooglePlay and Cafebazzar.

when using the Android Studio, I see assembleRelease and assembleCafeBazzar and assembleGooglePlay.

[image: jenkins]

when I use **./gradlew -q tasks --all** in jenkins, I Can't see assembleRelease in my tasks.
just I see assemble.
I use Jenkins to build the project. how can see assembleRelease in Jenkins?

```
    + ./gradlew -q tasks --all

------------------------------------------------------------
Tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Android tasks
-------------
app:sourceSets - Prints out all the source sets defined in this project.
core:sourceSets - Prints out all the source sets defined in this project.
skeleton:sourceSets - Prints out all the source sets defined in this project.

Build tasks
-----------
app:assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages.
core:assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages.
skeleton:assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages.
app:assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.
core:assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.
skeleton:assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.
app:build - Assembles and tests this project.
core:build - Assembles and tests this project.
skeleton:build - Assembles and tests this project.
app:buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
core:buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
skeleton:buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
app:buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
core:buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
skeleton:buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
app:clean - Deletes the build directory.
core:clean - Deletes the build directory.
skeleton:clean - Deletes the build directory.
app:cleanBuildCache - Deletes the build cache directory.
core:cleanBuildCache - Deletes the build cache directory.
skeleton:cleanBuildCache - Deletes the build cache directory.
```

Comment: We are having the same issue in GitLab CI with Docker executor. Any news?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, when i check out my project "assembleRelease" is not available as a task.
When i open the project in Android Studio and select "sync with gradle" there is some activity, afterwards i can execute "gradlew assembleRelease" from the command line.

I have no idea what exactly "sync with gradle" does. It seems there was a command that did something similar once, but it seems to be no longer available.

Edit:
It seems that the file local.properties is created by running "sync with gradle files". I created a sample to reproduce the issue in googles issuetracker and it seems that this file makes the difference between assembleRelease being available or not.

Edit2:
Fastlane is now running, i copy the local.properties file into the build directory during the setup.
According to a comment on my similar question [Gradle task assembleRelease not found in CI build, works with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080650/gradle-task-assemblerelease-not-found-in-ci-build-works-with-android-studio) it is because ANDROID_HOME is not set.